# SELECT query returns warning (expects parameter 1 to be resource)

Tags: php, mysql, select

**EDIT:** Thanks to all for your help (especially  @Marty McVry). I've just edited this question.

Table : purchase

```
 purchase_id     |   seller       |   buyer
        12       |      2         |     5
        29       |      5         |     2


 $check=query("SELECT (COUNT(*) >= 2) AS RESULT
 FROM   purchase a
     INNER JOIN purchase b
     ON a.seller = b.buyer AND
        a.buyer = b.seller
 WHERE  (a.seller = 2 AND a.buyer = 5) OR
        (a.seller = 5 AND a.buyer = 2)");

 $row = mysql_fetch_row($check);
 echo $row[0];
 if ($row[0] > 0) {
 foo
 } else {
 bar
 }
```

When I run this query, I get the following error:

`Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in line 180` (which is `$row = mysql_fetch_row($check);`).

What is going here?

FIY, here, `query()` connects to the DB and executes the SQL statement, possibly with parameters.

Comment: You count the number of rows that your query returns, but your query only returns 1 row, containing a count of the rows...

Comment: What does query() function do?

Comment: @MartyMcVry I edited my question, but I still have an issue. Query() executes the SQL statement, possibly with parameters. For the purpose of it, i just removed it here.

Comment: Please post the code you use for the query-function... It would seem that the database resource is not returned. (Do remember to delete possible usernames/passwords!)

Answer (score 2):

**After edit:**

As a side note: you query the db correctly, although you might want to look into PDO or mysqli.

The problem is what you do with the resultset afterwards.

You have to fetch the row to view the result:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($check);
echo $row[0];
if ($row[0] > 0) {
    // Code goes here
} else {
    // Other code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did exactly as you said, and here is the error I get: Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in line 180 (which is $row = mysql_fetch_row($check);). Any ideas?

Comment: `if (!$row) { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }` Put this right before the code I provided.

Comment: when I put it right between `$row = mysql_fetch_row($check);` and
`echo $row[0];` I get "invalid query" error.

Comment: You've connected to the DB-server? You've selected a DB you want to work in?

Comment: Yes. I'm fetching other data from my table on the same page. This query is the only one that doesn't work.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($check);` --> remove the space before the semicolon. Didn't notice it up until now...

Answer (score 1):

The line:

$result= (count($check));

gets the number of rows returned by your query, which in your case should always be 1.  You will want to fetch the data contained in that row and operate on that:

$row = myqli_fetch_row($check);

`$row` will then be an array, the first element should be the value of `RESULT` from your query.

Comment: fyi, I removed the query() function.  $connection= SQL query; 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($connection);
print_r ($row[0]);  This gives the following error::  mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you still need to execute the query.  `mysqli_fetch_row` expects it's argument to be the result of calling `mysqli_query`, which should be a [mysqli_result object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) See the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) for examples

Answer (score 0):

In your case, $result returns 1 all the time, because you just count($check)...
check again your code...